# Getting multiple data from first activity's EditText to second activity's TextView using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

**First Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btn;
    private Button btnsbm;
    private EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnsbm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefData", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("key",et.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        gotonextactivity();
    }

    public void gotonextactivity() {
        btnsbm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activty_2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What multiple data can you explain?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

While this question is answered.I would like to advise you that using `SharedPreferences` is not the way to transfer data between activities.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

If your requirements are such.Then you could explain your question a bit more for why you chose this approach.

A common practice amongst all android developers is to use extras in [intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) (check the section under extras).

you can use [putExtras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) to pass data to the next activity and retrieve them as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/3396197)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `Sharedpreference` to do that job, you can just put your data inside an `Intent` and get them inside the new activity.
First edit your button's `onClick()` to be like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activty_2.class);
        intent.putExtras("data", et.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
});
```

then inside your `Activty_2` `onCreate()` method you add

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("data"); // this is your text
}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it difficult my friend, you just need to use intent to pass data to your other activity.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putString("key",editText1.gettext().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Now get that data from you intent in SecondActivity in `onCreate()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getString("key");
textView.setText(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

write `editor.commit();` not `editor.apply();` . and please give proper error. Sharedpreference not filling or problem is something else?

Comment: `commit()` and `apply()` do the same job, just the difference is `commit()` has a return type boolean but `apply()` don't because almost no one cares for the return type so they added the `apply()`

Comment: You got data in sharedpreference or not??

Comment: In addition to @SaNtoRiaN's comment: `apply()` is also slightly faster.